# Why does the compiler warn when redeclaring base class's readwrite property as readonly in subclass?

Tags: objective-c, properties

The Apple doc quoted later seems to indicate this is permissible, though I'll admit never having a reason to do it in a subclass until now.

I have a base class with a public readwrite property and a subclass where I redeclare the property as readonly.  The subclass also has a class extension which again redeclares the property as readwrite  to achieve the common "public readonly, private readwrite" Objective-C pattern.  However, I get the following compiler warning:

```
warning: Semantic Issue: Attribute 'readonly' of property 'foo' restricts attribute 'readwrite' of property inherited from 'Base'
```

I'm using Xcode 4.1 build 4B110 with LLVM 2.1 (though LLVM GCC4.2 and GCC4.2 give the same warning) on 10.7.

Here's a stripped-down example which exhibits the compiler warning:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Base : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL foo;
@end

@implementation Base
@dynamic foo;
@end

// Subclass
@interface Sub : Base
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL foo;
@end

// Class extension 
@interface Sub ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL foo;
@end

@implementation Sub
@dynamic foo;  // it warns with @synthesize as well
@end
```

Here's a relevant passage from Apple's [*The Objective-C Programming Language*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html):

> Property Redeclaration
>
> You can redeclare a property in a subclass, but (with the exception of 
>   readonly versus readwrite) you must repeat its attributes in whole in 
>   the subclasses. The same holds true for a property declared in a 
>   category or protocol—while the property may be redeclared in a category
>   or protocol, the property’s attributes must be repeated in whole.
>
> If you declare a property in one class as readonly, you can redeclare it
>   as readwrite in a class extension (see “Extensions”), in a protocol, or 
>   in a subclass (see “Subclassing with Properties”). In the case of a class
>   extension redeclaration, the fact that the property was redeclared prior
>   to any @synthesize statement causes the setter to be synthesized. The 
>   ability to redeclare a read-only property as read/write enables two 
>   common implementation patterns: a mutable subclass of an immutable class
>   (NSString, NSArray, and NSDictionary are all examples) and a property that
>   has a public API that is readonly but a private readwrite implementation 
>   internal to the class. The following example shows using a class extension
>   to provide a property that is declared as read-only in the public header 
>   but is redeclared privately as read/write.

I redeclare public readonly properties readwrite in class extensions all the time, but I guess I've never had cause to do it an a subclass.  However, unless I'm reading it wrong, the paragraphs above seem to indicate that it's kosher.  Can anyone set me straight and/or reconcile the apparent conflict between the docs and the compiler?

Why do I want to do this?  My real-world situation is more complex, of course.  I can make design changes to work around this if needed, but this seemed like the least-friction alternative (the need to do this at all is being driven by other changes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It says you can redeclare a `readonly` property as `readwrite` but you're doing the opposite. You can't/shouldn't do it because it's possible to do this:

```
Sub* s = [[[Sub alloc] init] autorelease];
Base* b = s; 
b.foo = YES; //legal for `Base` objects, but not legal for `Sub` objects
```

It's a violation of the [the Liskov Substitution Priciple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: What Tom said.  It doesn't make sense to make a subclass readonly when the superclass offers readwrite publicly.  Generally, you add mutability going down the class hierarchy (see the various Immutable -> Mutable class cluster examples provided in the OS).

Comment: Thanks Tom and bbum. I (should) know better. I think I spent too long this weekend mulling over my actual problem and lost sight of first principles. I even had a second chance to catch myself, but my brain somehow filtered out "or in a subclass" in the doc's second paragraph through multiple readings. After a dinner break and coming back to your answers, I feel a little silly about this one. Thanks for some clarity, and I enjoyed the Liskov link!