# Cocos2d SneakyInput - Attribute read only restricts attribute readwrite of property inherited from

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to add [SneakyInput](https://github.com/sneakyness/SneakyInput) to my current [Cocos2D-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) project.  I had to adjust a few things to get it working (since the github source is outdated).  Long story short, everything is working except I get two warnings from the following code (denoted with comments):

Error:

> Attribute 'readonly' of property 'color' restricts attribute
>   'readwrite' of property inherited from 'CCRGBAProtocol'

[ColoredCircleSprite.h](https://github.com/sneakyness/SneakyInput/blob/master/Classes/ColoredCircleSprite.h):

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface ColoredCircleSprite : CCNode <CCRGBAProtocol, CCBlendProtocol> {
    float       radius_;
    GLubyte     opacity_;
    ccColor3B   color_;

    NSUInteger numberOfSegments;
    GLfloat *circleVertices_;

    ccBlendFunc blendFunc_;
}

@property (nonatomic,readwrite) float radius;

/** Opacity: conforms to CCRGBAProtocol protocol */
@property (nonatomic,readonly) GLubyte opacity;  //<--------- ERROR thrown here!!
/** Opacity: conforms to CCRGBAProtocol protocol */
@property (nonatomic,readonly) ccColor3B color;  //<--------- ERROR thrown here!!
/** BlendFunction. Conforms to CCBlendProtocol protocol */
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) ccBlendFunc blendFunc;

/** creates a Circle with color and radius */
+ (id) circleWithColor: (ccColor4B)color radius:(GLfloat)r;

/** initializes a Circle with color and radius */
- (id) initWithColor:(ccColor4B)color radius:(GLfloat)r;

- (BOOL) containsPoint:(CGPoint)point;

@end
```

The only information on this error I could find came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142390/why-does-the-compiler-warn-when-redeclaring-base-classs-readwrite-property-as-r).  The accepted answer states:

> It says you can redeclare a readonly property as readwrite but you're
>   doing the opposite. You can't/shouldn't do it because it's possible to
>   do this:

```
Sub* s = [[[Sub alloc] init] autorelease];
Base* b = s; 
b.foo = YES; //legal for `Base` objects, but not legal for `Sub` objects
```

> It's a violation of the the [Liskov Substitution Priciple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

My problem is that I don't entirely understand the wikipedia article.  I know that the issue stems from inheritance.  The whole A [is-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) B thing from [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).  Etc.  I am just wondering what the appropriate way to approach and fix this is?  I'm one of those people who enjoys having 0 warnings/errors.  Is there a simple approach to remedy this warning, suppress it, etc?  I'd also appreciate some explanation as to "why" exactly your approach works (since everyone, including myself, could learn from it).

Comment: just make the property readwrite

Comment: Why then, was it originally set to readonly in the code?  Im presuming because they didn't want it to be modifiable, however the parent allowed these properties to be readwrite.  Could there be any issues by allowing them to be readwrite?  Or perhaps another way to enforce only reading?

Comment: sneakyinput is way old, at that time the compiler didn't warn about these things. You'll notice any issues when you actually do change opacity or color. If it works fine, fine. If not, don't change them or fix the code.

Comment: I've noticed the aged'ness.  Unfortunately all of the books for learning cocos2D are rather dated as well and it seems like a quality resource.  My plan is to fix the code, which is why I asked this question :P  I have searched for a simple solution, and so far, I have come up short.  So instead of wasting more time, I thought maybe someone more knowledgeable than I could make a suggestion to remedy this and also teach me their ways at the same time.